# WSLg: how to run GUI WSL app as root?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, wslg

I'm getting started with WSLg, and I can run apps like nautilus OK, but I can't run them as root.

If I run it with the Windows "Run as administrator" option, then the app just seems to run as a normal user:

```
(base) ian@IansDesktop:~$ sudo ps aux | grep nautilus
ian        521  4.0  0.8 573876 70432 pts/1    Ssl+ 21:55   0:14 nautilus --new-window
```

If I try to run from the terminal with `sudo` it exits with an error:

```
(base) ian@IansDesktop:~$ sudo nautilus --new-window

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:1025): WARNING **: 22:02:15.647: Error on getting connection: Failed to load SPARQL backend: Error spawning command line ?dbus-launch --autolaunch= --binary-syntax --close-stderr?: Child process exited with code 1
```

How can I start a WSLg app as root?

Comment: What distribution are you running?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Ubuntu, 20.04

Comment: Also what's your goal in running Nautilus as root?  The root WSL user has no more privileges than your Windows user.  In other words, running it as root won't give you the ability to change files in Windows that require Administrator privileges.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds surely root nautilus user can cut and paste files, rather than just view them? Ultimately I want to make sure the file browser I'm using can "see" everything, but my question was posed to be more general because there are definitely GUI tools I may want to use in future that require root.

Comment: My point is, since you were trying to run it in via "Run as Administrator" (which would be a Windows admin account, of course), that running as WSL `root` will not have the permissions of the Windows Admin user.  In other words, it can edit all files *inside* a WSL instance, but it will not be able to change files on the Windows drive that require Admin.  So as long as you understand those limitations, yes, absolutely, it can still be useful to run something as root (e.g. gvim) to edit files.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I didn't expect the 'Run as administrator' option to work, but before posting (and actually in this case, during) I like to check the 'obvious' options I may have missed.

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't been able to reproduce your issue, let me share what I know (so far), since it got too long for a comment/chat.  I just set up a fresh 20.04 WSL2 (Windows 11) distribution to attempt to reproduce your issue, but it works for me -- I'm able to launch into WSLg with `sudo nautilus --new-window`.

[This Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1104648/1165986) on a question referencing a similar error seems to indicate a conflict in trying to run more than one Nautilus instance, but I'm not able to reproduce that way either.

A couple of notes:

First, and most importantly, this probably isn't an issue with all GUI apps.  I would recommend trying:

```
sudo apt install xterm
sudo xterm
```

I *expect* that this will either work for you (with a root shell in xterm), or help us identify your root issue (no pun intended; just a happy accident).

You might also try `wsl --terminate <distribution_name>` and trying Nautilus-as-root in a freshly booted instance.

And, there's also a chance that `sudo -E nautilus --new-window` might give you a different result, but I think that's unlikely based on my testing.  Still, worth a shot.

Ultimately, one important thing to realize is that running Gnome apps under WSLg is not as simple as running most other GUI apps.  Gnome apps have a high-level of dependency on many other inter-connected features, such as:

- D-Bus
- Systemd
- gio/gvfs

I thought I would be able to track your particular issue to one of these, but I haven't been able to connect-the-dots to reproduce it on my system yet.

It's typically *possible* to overcome Gnome issues on WSL, but it definitely requires more effort than other apps.

For instance, even as your regular user, you'll probably get an `Operation not supported` error in Nautilus if you attempt to access the "Trash" feature.  This can be overcome with:

```
dbus-launch nautilus
```

... which will launch Nautilus inside a D-bus user session, enabling `gvfs` support through D-bus.

Which raises a final thought -- You might also try:

```
sudo dbus-launch nautilus
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, however none of your suggestions worked for me unfortunately. For now I'm resigned to the terminal I suppose!

Comment: @IanNewson Even xterm?  What error are you getting there?